# Java Attach API: How to set agent properties?

Tags: java, instrumentation, agent

The Java Attach API for JDK6 provides a method `getAgentProperties()` on `VirtualMachine`:

> **public abstract Properties getAgentProperties() 
>         throws IOException**
>
> Returns the current agent properties in the target virtual
>    machine.  The target virtual machine can maintain a list of
>    properties on behalf of agents. The manner in which this is
>    done, the names of the properties, and the types of values that
>    are allowed, is implementation specific. Agent properties are
>    typically used to store communication end-points and other
>    agent configuration details. For example, a debugger agent
>    might create an agent property for its transport address.
>
> This method returns the agent properties whose key and value is
>    a String. Properties whose key or value is not a String are
>    omitted. If there are no agent properties maintained in the
>    target virtual machine then an empty property list is returned.

(from the [Java Attach API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#getAgentProperties%28%29))

My question is, how to **set** these properties on the other side (i.e.
within the JVM where the agent is running) ?

The documentation for the [instrument API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html?is-external=true) doesn't talk about this either.

Comment: I don't think you can.  What is it you need to do?

Comment: I want to check out the state of the agent. I.e. I have an agent which listens on a port and can be started and stopped. For the moment, I use a system property, which I set, when the agent is started and removed when it is stopped. This works, but it would be better if I wouldn't pollute the global system properties namespace.

Comment: From the Javadoc above: "_For example, a debugger agent might create an agent property for its transport address_". So it must be possible someone to create such a property.

Comment: @RolandHuß Did you ever manage to find the answer for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I stick to the solution described above, using a system property for the state. That works fine although it is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

On Hot Spot VM you can set agent properties using sun.misc.VMSupport.getAgentProperties().